# Grails: SpringSecurity roleHierarchy not working as expected

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, roles

I am using the springsecurity plugin in Grails 2.0.1. My role hierarchy and other s2 properties are shown below.

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'myApp.security.User'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'myApp.security.UserRole'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.authority.className = 'myApp.security.Role'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl="/index"
grails.plugins.springsecurity.securityConfigType = "Annotation"

//grails.plugins.springsecurity.rejectIfNoRule = true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.roleHierarchy = '''
    ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_OWNER_TRANSFER_PRIVILEGE
    ROLE_OWNER_TRANSFER_PRIVILEGE > ROLE_OWNER
    ROLE_OWNER > ROLE_USER_WRITE
'''
```

As per the documentation, if my @secured annotation allows ROLE_USER_WRITE, then all other roles need to be allowed access as well. Similarly, if I were to use a   tag, then ROLE_OWNER, ROLE_OWNER_TRANSFER_PRIVILEGE and ROLE_ADMIN must equate to true. But, this doesn't work, instead I am forced to list each role. I checked the debug logs and it looks like  this

```
2012-06-01 09:28:14,802 [pool-5-thread-1] DEBUG hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl  - setHierarchy() - The following role hierarchy was set: 
        ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_OWNER_TRANSFER_PRIVILEGE
        ROLE_OWNER_TRANSFER_PRIVILEGE > ROLE_OWNER
        ROLE_OWNER > ROLE_USER_WRITE

2012-06-01 09:28:14,802 [pool-5-thread-1] DEBUG hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl  - buildRolesReachableInOneStepMap() - From role ROLE_ADMIN one can reach r
ole ROLE_OWNER_TRANSFER_PRIVILEGE in one step.
2012-06-01 09:28:14,802 [pool-5-thread-1] DEBUG hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl  - buildRolesReachableInOneStepMap() - From role ROLE_OWNER_TRANSFER_PRIVIL
EGE one can reach role ROLE_OWNER in one step.
2012-06-01 09:28:14,802 [pool-5-thread-1] DEBUG hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl  - buildRolesReachableInOneStepMap() - From role ROLE_OWNER one can reach r
ole ROLE_USER_WRITE in one step.
2012-06-01 09:28:14,803 [pool-5-thread-1] DEBUG hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl  - buildRolesReachableInOneOrMoreStepsMap() - From role ROLE_ADMIN one can 
reach [ROLE_OWNER_TRANSFER_PRIVILEGE, ROLE_USER_WRITE, ROLE_OWNER] in one or more steps.
...
```

It seems like the role hierarchies are being created, but they are not enforced while the application is running. What am I doing wrong and how do I get this to work as per the documentation?

Comment: Well, turns out I had a typo. Which makes this question redundant with a bounty :( What do I do now? I can't delete it, close or do anything with it. Can the mods help me out here?

Comment: Hi Ritesh, I don't think you can get back the bounty. You can answer your own question and accept the answer, though. Maybe in the future someone with the same problem will appreciate your answer

Comment: Per the faq, once a bounty is offered, it's gone.  I agree though, the point of SO is to help people, so at least you can answer your own question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have answered the question with an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

roleHierarchies need to have a complete tree structure to work. In my question I represented half the hierarchy, it turned out be an incomplete tree representation. Something like :

```
ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_OWNER_TRANSFER_PRIVILEGE
ROLE_OWNER_TRANSFER_PRIVILEGE > ROLE_OWNER
ROLE_OWNER > ROLE_USER_WRITE
ROLE_USER > ROLE_READ
```

Here the ROLE_USER and ROLE_USER_WRITE are disconnected subtrees of hierarchies and spring security wasn't, understandably, able to resolve this while resolving permissions.