# Spring security @secure not working with role hierarchy in Grails

Tags: grails, spring-security

My Grails is 2.2.1
Java 1.7
Spring-security-core 1.2.7.3
Spring-security-ui 0.2

Similar to the issue in [Spring security @secure not working with role hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19516208/spring-security-secure-not-working-with-role-hierarchy) the security hierarchy is not being respected.

I have three user roles  ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER, ROLE_USER_NOT_CONFIRMED

Based on the Spring documentation http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/hierarchicalRoles.html

I added the following code into the Config.groovy:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.roleHierarchy = '''
    ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_USER
'''
```

and based on [Grails: SpringSecurity roleHierarchy not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844309/grails-springsecurity-rolehierarchy-not-working-as-expected) I tried:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.roleHierarchy = '''
    ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_USER
    ROLE_USER > ROLE_USER_NOT_CONFIRMED
'''
```

I'm not what the syntax is to add DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler in grails or if it is required.

In a Controller Method I preface with @Secured(['ROLE_USER']) and when I'm logged in as ROLE_ADMIN it throws a permissions error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this configuration is ok for the new release of the plugin (version 2.0). Could you try to modify your config with this code (**'s'** after plugin):

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.roleHierarchy = '''
    ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_USER
    ROLE_USER > ROLE_USER_NOT_CONFIRMED
'''
```

Hope that helps.